# Firebase http functions api suddenly stopped working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Cloud functions return:

> Error: Server Error
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

Last time the issue occurred Firebase team has updated their [**status dashboard**](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18018) with an investigation issue.

Right now it seems that everything is just fine according to their [**dashboard**](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

My http functions worked perfectly, suddenly everything stopped. Is it Firebase issue? Haven't they updated the dashboard yet? What can I do in order to be sure it's not my side issue?

Note: Although **I can** redeploy the functions from my local computer to Firebase (which is also not helping to solve the issue), **I cannot** redeploy functions directly from google cloud functions editor.

If someone is facing the same issue please comment below so we will be able to know that it is a wide problem.

Thanks a lot

**Update (06.09.20 18:30)**

Right now it seems that everything is working again. If it was a real Firebase outage you will be able to see the investigation in the [dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

Comment: If you think there is a problem with Firebase services, you should contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks I have sent the issue.
If it's an real Firebase outage, it will be updated at the Firebase status dashboard within 4 hours.
https://status.firebase.google.co